# Spring Cloud Gateway altering form data does not work

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-cloud-gateway

I defined this GatewayFilter:

**EDIT** More context information:

What I would like to achieve is to avoid the client providing its credentials to get an access token from an authorization server.
The client sends a POST request with user's credentials (username/password) and the gateway adds all complementary information like `scope`, `client_id`, `grant_type` etc... before forwarding the request to the authorization server.

```
@Component
public class OAuth2CredentialsAppenderGatewayFilterFactory extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<OAuth2CredentialsAppenderGatewayFilterFactory.Config> {

    public OAuth2CredentialsAppenderGatewayFilterFactory() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();

            ServerHttpRequest.Builder requestBuilder = exchange.getRequest().mutate();

            if ("x-www-form-urlencoded".equals(request.getHeaders().getContentType().getSubtype())) {

               //This code is not executed, the call of formData.put does not do anything, even a breakpoint is not reached!
                if (request.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.POST)) {
                      exchange.getFormData().map(formData -> { 
                        formData.put("key1", List.of("value1")); 
                        formData.put("key2", List.of("value2"));
                        formData.put("key3", List.of("value3"));
                        return formData;
                    });
                }

            //This part of code works well, the header is added to the forwarded request 
              requestBuilder.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,
                            "Basic " + Base64Utils.encodeToString((this.uiClientId + ":" + this.uiClientSecret).getBytes()));
            }

            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(requestBuilder.build()).build());
        };
    }
}
```

I use the filter like this:

```
  - id: keycloak_token_route
    uri: http://localhost:8180
    predicates:
    - Path=/kc/token  
    filters:
    - OAuth2CredentialsAppender
    - SetPath=/auth/realms/main/protocol/openid-connect/token
    - name: RequestRateLimiter 
      args:
        key-resolver: "#{@userIpKeyResolver}"
        redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 20 
        redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 30 
        denyEmptyKey: false
```

The filter is well invoked but altering the incoming request body does not work.
I am new to the reactive world so I am a bit confused, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show your configuration and dependencies please

Comment: Ok. I see what's happening. Unfortunately, I'm not able to provide a fun answer with examples. The map never happens because there's no subscription. To do it you have to plug it in to the filter chain. Instead of returning form data, return the filter chain statement

Comment: @spencergibb Thank you, I finally found a solution which seems to work. Reactive programming is just insane… it’s absolutely not obvious.

Comment: Akuma8, would you be able to post your solution?

Comment: @ATrubka sure, I was on holidays so I didn't see your comment but if you still need the solution, please let me know. I'll post it asap

Comment: Akuma8, no problem. I was able to figure it out on my own. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @ATrubka I took few minutes to add my solution, hope it will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

For those who would like to do the same thing, this is how I solved my problem. Again I am not an expert of Reactive programming, I am still learning it so it might be a better answer.

```
@Component
public class OAuth2CredentialsAppenderGatewayFilterFactory extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<OAuth2CredentialsAppenderGatewayFilterFactory.Config> {
    @Value("${uiservice.clientId}")
    private String uiClientId;

    @Value("${uiservice.clientSecret}")
    private String uiClientSecret;

    public OAuth2CredentialsAppenderGatewayFilterFactory() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {

        return (ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) -> {
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
            ServerHttpRequest.Builder requestBuilder = exchange.getRequest().mutate();

            if (nonNull(request.getHeaders().getContentType()) && request.getHeaders().getContentType().equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)) {

                if (requireNonNull(request.getMethod()).equals(HttpMethod.POST)) {
                   //Use this filter to modify the request body
                    ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config requestConf = new ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config()
                            .setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
                            .setRewriteFunction(String.class, String.class, this.completeRequestBody());

                    requestBuilder.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, base64Encoding(this.uiClientId, this.uiClientSecret));

                    return new ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory().apply(requestConf).filter(exchange.mutate().request(requestBuilder.build()).build(), chain);
                }
            }

            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(requestBuilder.build()).build());
        };
    }


    /** Add some config params if needed */
    public static class Config {
    }

    /** Complete request by adding required information to get the access token. Here we can get 2 type of token: client_credentials or password. If the param client_only=true we should get a client_credentials token */
    private RewriteFunction<String, String> completeRequestBody() {

        return (ServerWebExchange ex, String requestBody) -> {
            requireNonNull(requestBody, "Body is required");
            //if body contains only this, we should get a client_credentials token
            var idForClientCredentialsOnly = "client=ui&client_only=true";

            String finalRequestBody;
            var joiner = new StringJoiner("");

            if (idForClientCredentialsOnly.equalsIgnoreCase(requestBody)) {
                joiner.add("grant_type=").add("client_credentials");
            }
            else {
                joiner.add(requestBody);
                if (!containsIgnoreCase(requestBody, "grant_type")) {
                    joiner.add("&grant_type=").add("password");
                }
            }
            if (!containsIgnoreCase(requestBody, "scope")) {
                joiner.add("&scope=").add("uiclient");//I use Keycloak so I specify the scope to get some extra information
            }
            finalRequestBody = joiner.toString();

            return Mono.just(isBlank(finalRequestBody) ? requestBody : finalRequestBody);
        };
    }
}
```